# Html 5 or bootstrap to use for responsive layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie in UX/UI. I see that html5 also says responsive design and Bootstrap also telling the same. So which1 do i use for my layout. What is beneficial over the other. I want to get my basics right.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML5 boilerplate responsive (initializr)? Because You can definitely use HTML5 with Bootstrap.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133639/bootstrap-and-html5-semantic-tags

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 and Bootstrap are totally different entities, only when you use them together in conjunction that you get a responsive site. Bootstrap is a CSS framework that allows you to build up a responsive site using predefined css classes and some javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want.
If you want everything to write youself, then plain HTML5. On the other hand there a Bootstrap - CSS framework which does most of boring stuff and also uses HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use Bootstrap with HTML5. If you want to do everything by your own while keeping the site light-weight, then you can do plain HTML5-CSS. But Bootstrap handles almost all of UI responsiveness, at the expense of weight.

In the end, it's your call if you want to create a light-weight and self-written design(which is going to be harder) or add a little more weight, for a great number of functionalities you can just basically apply in ease.

Comment: For make page responsive in HTML5 should i use boilerplate?? I have read everywhere that HTML5 is mobile friendly, What does it mean actually.

Comment: If you want to create a website NOT from scratch, then by any means, use a boilerplate. In fact, Bootstrap is a boilerplate in a way. But if you want to create it without the hassle of trying to override functions/styles predefined by other users and without the added weight, then do so yourself, but it's going to be a bit harder since you're going to almost everything yourself.

My advice: If you think the site you're making is done before and you don't want to start from scratch, use a boilerplate. If you want to do everything by yourself, don't use a boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Html5 isn't responsive but bootstrap is. Responsive isn't a HTML thing but a CSS thing. Usually you want users to be able to view your apps from different devices without any problems (such as cluttering) and for that porpouse we've got **responsive** and **adaptative** (both of which are CSS related).

Let's say you've got a div tag and you give it width and height propperties, such as 500x500. In large desktop's screens it could seem to be normal size, but on mobile phones it could take the entire screen or even more. So if you give it its size as a percentage such as `width: 10%;` and `height: 10%;` it would be a responsive-like solution.

Then it is bootstrap as a responsive framework with has its [grid layout system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that allows you to give different porcentages to the same HTML tag in different devices, using `class="col-<device>-<columns>"` (of course you could use more than 1 class for the same HTML tag). Bootstrap has 4 devices:

- xs: mobiles
- sm: tablets
- md: desktops
- lg: TVs

And it also has 12 colums for each row (it doesn't handle height manually, height increases as needed unless you manually define it in your css). So , our previous example could end being something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-5"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJBvbL) you've got a codepen example. (Try resizing its width)

And it would take different sizes for different devices. So at this point you could notice 2 things, there is something more (beyond of porcentages/responsiveness) going on here, and I still haven't mention what adaptative is. Ok, adaptative is just conditionally using some CSS rules for different screen sizes (not neccesarely as porcentages) [by using media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) an example of adaptative layout would be Youtube and an example of responsive layout would be Twitter.

In addition bootstrap also provides you with some [js functionality](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), some default [css components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) (such as [navigator](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), [tables](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels), and much more), and also a set of [font-icons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples).

Comment: U mean to say what ever media queries we write that is adaptive and what ever we use grid layouts in bootstrap is responsive??

Comment: @Hacker When you use sizes as porcentages you are using responsiveness , when you use [media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) you are using adaptative.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally the answer is that Bootstrap is more complete, it has more buttons, menus, slide shows, etc. that you can quickly pick up and use.  The downside is that the result will look like a Bootstrap site (just as you can usually tell a WordPress site).

HTML5 (I presume you mean HTML5 Boilerplate otherwise you are comparing apples to oranges), is more basic, and you will need to edit the HTML and CSS more.  On the other hand, because it is more basic, you can have more flexibility with it.